# How to convert CHM to PDF in Ubuntu?

Tags: format-conversion

I have a large CHM file but tired of clicking *next* button. What's the best way to convert them to PDF?

P.S: terminal way please.

Comment: Related: [How to open CHM documents?](http://askubuntu.com/q/28136/62483)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next search returned `chm2pdf`

```
apt-cache search chm pdf
```

Have you tried it? You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install chm2pdf
```

Comment: In Ubunto 20.4: No such package

Comment: You can get the code from here https://code.google.com/archive/p/chm2pdf/ or here https://github.com/Arnoques/chm2pdf 
Unfortunately, all links to www.karakas-online.de are dead, but you ca still get the information from here https://web.archive.org/web/20121101231347/http://www.karakas-online.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10275 and here https://web.archive.org/web/20131022132109/http://karakas-online.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10969

Comment: From AUR I found this https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/chm-to-pdf which has a download link for a Perl script from 2012.